# Displaying ArrayList data in JTable

Tags: java, swing

Here I have an ArrayList named vehicles that has several items of data type AutoRickshaw and ElectricScooter, here in the code below I will be making two different JTables to display data of AutoRickshaw and ElectricScooter. This table however loops to the vehicles.size() which causes to create empty rows (which would have data of ElectricScooter).The output is shown here [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLXTX.png). I want these empty rows to not be displayed or be removed.

```
for (int i = 0; i < vehicles.size(); i++) {
    if (vehicles.get(i) instanceof AutoRickshaw) {
        autoRickshaw = (AutoRickshaw) vehicles.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
            data[i][j] = autoRickshaw.getVehicleId();
            data[i][j] = autoRickshaw.getVehicleName();
            data[i][j] = autoRickshaw.getVehicleWeight();
            data[i][j] = autoRickshaw.getVehicleColor();
            data[i][j] = autoRickshaw.getVehicleSpeed();
            data[i][j] = autoRickshaw.getEngineDisplacement();
            data[i][j] = autoRickshaw.getTorque();
            data[i][j] = autoRickshaw.getNumberOfSeats();
            data[i][j] = autoRickshaw.getFuelTankCapacity();
            data[i][j] = autoRickshaw.getGroundClearance();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this a bit by using DefaultTableModel. It has addRow method which can you can use to add the rows.

[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow(java.lang.Object[])](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow(java.lang.Object%5B%5D))

You can also fix the problem here by creating separate lists for different types of vehicles and then creating cell data Object[][] of required size.